# Why does this code pass a parameter to a constructor when there is no __init__ method?

Tags: python

So, I am reading some code online and I came across the following class definition and I'm a little confused;

```
class MyClass(OrderedDict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self.iteritems()))
```

Elsewhere in the code there is the following line;

```
MyClass(my_OD)
```

Where `my_OD` is an ordered dictionary.  My question is, how can you pass an argument to this class when there is no `__init__` method?  Where is this variable being assigned within the class?  I'm coming from Java and I'm fairly certain that in Java you cannot pass an argument to a class without a constructor so this behavior is foreign to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class `MyClass` inherits from `OrderedDict`:

```
class MyClass(OrderedDict):
```

Since `MyClass` doesn't have an `__init__` method specified, it calls the init method of the OrderedDict class. So the `my_OD` argument to the constructor gets passed on to the OrderedDict. Btw, `__init__` is not technically the *constructor*.

The purpose of this `MyClass` is to be an OrderedDict which computes the `hash` of its instances in a different way than OrderedDict does. Specifically, `OrderedDict` doesn't have a `__hash__`, that's defined on `dict`s and in that case, the hash is defined as `None` - so dicts are un-hashable. `MyClass` changes that adds a way to get the hash, while the rest of the functionality is the same `OrderedDict`s and `dict`s.

Comment: So this would explain why you're able to call iteritems() on 'self' -- a MyClass object?

Comment: Yes, `iteritems` is a method on `dict` objects and OrderedDict inherits from `dict` so `MyClass.iteritems` actually calls `dict.iteritems`.